# Prestashop Products Image Resize

Tags: javascript, html, image, css, image-resizing

Product Image resize css coding or theme modules 
I want product image resize size will be Reduce in top and bottom white  space pls help me as it it is image pls My Site URL http://104.131.84.58/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Crop the image closer to the left and right edges of the product. That will cause the image to fill more vertical space.

Assuming I understand your question correctly.